# What did Lucy mean by "We never really die"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, lucy

In Lucy there was a car chase. Lucy was driving and there was a police officer in the car. Lucy was driving extremely fast when officer said:

> Better be late than dead

In reply Lucy said:

> We never really die

What did she mean? At the end of the movie we saw Lucy tell the officer that "I am everywhere." I'm guessing she became immortal, but normal people are mortal. What did the writer actually mean? Even Lucy didn't know at that time what's gonna happen when her brain usability reaches 100%.

Comment: Never mind the fact that the whole "you only use 10% of your brain" line is bunk.  That's like saying, you only use 10% of your muscles.  Sure, at any one time.  The only time you use 100% of either of them would be if you are having a seizure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet it had something to do with her consciousness never really disappearing. My interpretation is that, in the movie, bodies are mortal. They die. But a person's consciousness, their awareness and ability to interact with the physical universe, is timeless and is not tied to the mortal body they inhabit for a while. (That's just my guess. The movie was pretty trippy and didn't explain everything fully.)

Comment: Yeah may be you're right. May be that's the thought behind this line. But it's not clear to me how that awareness and consciousness stays after someone's death. Lets see if writer or director said something about this and if there is any reference about it.

Comment: I'd love to hear something directly from the writer or director too!

Answer (score 1):

In law of conservation energy - Energy can be neither created nor destroyed, but can change form. Our life force is some kind of energy stuck in a mortal body.

The body can be destroyed but the life force cannot. Our life force only transform into a being, living on another plane of existence where body is not needed. Either that is life after death or something else, well no one will know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

She talks about our [consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness) (a state of awareness, [a state of matter](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/next/physics/physicists-say-consciousness-might-be-a-state-of-matter/http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/next/physics/physicists-say-consciousness-might-be-a-state-of-matter/)) that is immortal and it never dies after death.

She proves that at the end of the movie by [ascending into heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entering_Heaven_alive) ([higher planes of existences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(esotericism))) when she becomes [omnipresent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipresence) cosmic [consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness#Spiritual_approaches) (Ultimate Human, Universe itself, [enlightened being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightenment_(spiritual)), a godlike being) by being fully aware.

Read more: [What does Lucy turn into at the very end?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65530/what-does-lucy-turn-into-at-the-very-end)

Answer (score 0):

reff : [http://www.thisisbarry.com/#!Lucy-2014-Explained](http://www.thisisbarry.com/#!Lucy-2014-Explained/ce4s/56a4cf970cf22a61ccc963b7)

There are a few philosophies that the East believes in.

> I'm not sure if research was done into the Indian philosophies around
> dvaitam, advaitam and vishishtadvaitam for this film.
>
> **Dvaitam**: Is the concept that most of the world follows. There is a divine power and there are the creations of the divine power. This is
> dualism.
>
> **Advaitam**: Is the concept of one single reality. Atman (the living soul) is the same as Bhraman (single reality). What life is, is merely
> an illusion that we perceive. Everything living is merely a combined
> conscience. To get to that realization is deemed attaining Nirvana.
>
> **Vishishtadvaitam**: is the concept of one single reality too. The difference is that here we have the divine power has multiplicity.
> This means the living exist in a pseudo-singular existence, but death
> causes the being to unite with the single reality.
>
> Lucy explains
> that “we never really die”. This pairs well with the concept of
> Vishishtadvaitam where death only leads to rejoining a singular
> reality. Lucy, based on the concepts of Advaitam, has attained Nirvana
> and is now aware that she's part of that singular reality and doesn't
> need her physical body anymore.

Comment: I saw that many of your answers lately contain references to this specific blog (as well as past answers of yours usually contained references to another specific blog). Since the blog posts usually seem to be relevant to those answers and the inspiration for them, this is of course advisable and not in any way a problem. However, if you are in any way affiliated as a person to this blog and its creators, you should mention this in your answers, be it only to refute any possible accusations of improper advertizement.

Comment: Sure, these are blogs that I follow closely.

Comment: So you are *not* an author of them or affiliated with their creators?

Comment: No, should i not have copy-pasted content with reference? I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Oh, did you? Well, you can do that, but you should definitely put it in quote markup. But that wasn't what I was talking about. *If* you were the author of those posts or in any way related to the creators of that blog, then you should have clarified that in the answer in order to prevent any accusations for improper advertizement (more blatantly called "spamming"). But since you say you aren't, there doesn't seem to be a problem. But about the quoting, I didn't realize you copied things wholesale from that site. If that's the case, then you definitely have to put it in quote markup.

Comment: done, dang-it, I need to revisit a few of my answers then. I'll do it over the next couple of days. I thought the "reff" was enough, I'll add the quotes to other answers where I've done a copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the transformation is not that she became immortal, but that she became aware of that nature, and became more in tune with it while still in her physical human form.

Answer (score -1):

I think no one really knows what happens to us when we die cos even the dead can not speak to us clearly to explain where they are or what has happened to their once inhabited bodies... 
The point is Life is what we have right now, let's use it well.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is in Daoism:

> There is in Daoism, as with the Greek Heraclitus, a strong awareness of the process of change. Both nature and human beings are continuously undergoing transformations. The processes of Nature move between polarities and humans move to new perspectives. Given this situation, it is useless to expect clear definitions and continuity of structures. If one has an understanding of the nature of things and follows the natural course, one can avoid being affected by sorrow or joy. Emotion can be counteracted with reason and understanding. For example, a man of understanding will not be angry when rain prevents him from going out, but a child often will.
>
> Zhuangzi himself shows indifference toward death and decries the common practice of mourning because the mourner assumes knowledge of the unknown and pretends his dislike of it. In contrast, by his understanding of the nature of things, the sage is no longer affected by external factors and the changes of the world. On this passage the great commentator Kuo Hsiang comments: “When ignorant, he felt sorry. When he understood, he was no longer affected. This teaches man to disperse emotion with reason.
>
> If life and death are but phases within the cycle of change, then there is no difference between the living and the dead. Mortality only becomes a problem and a source of sorrow,because man cannot free himself from his categorisation of life and existence. In the physical sense, man must die and there is no escape. But, if man can understand Nature’s way and embrace the Dao, then he lives as long as the Dao. Zhuangzi defies death by saying that if (after death) his left arm became a rooster, he would simply use it to mark the time of night. Man may die indeed, but his essence as part of the universal essence lives on forever. This is the metaphysical view of immortality in the Zhuangzi.

https://philosophynow.org/issues/27/Death_in_Classical_Daoist_Thought

Answer (score -1):

According to Daoism (mandarin pronunciation) and Buddhism, the spirits never die, they will reincarnate.

Emanuel Swendenborg, a famous Swedish scientist, has the same belief. He even visited the "spirit world" and wrote many books about it.