# Did Lucy become a Buddha?

Tags: lucy

The experience of [Lucy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_%282014_film%29) appears very similar to what was experienced by Gautama Buddha. She said that she has no desire and she can feel or see the whole universe. One of the most important part of becoming a Buddha is having no desire for worldly things. They also say that a Buddha can see the whole universe.

Did Lucy become a Buddha? Was the writer of this movie inspired by Buddhism?

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28174/49, http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/25116/49 and http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/25114/49.

Comment: If become a Buddha can be through "LUCY" way than might as well I just eat fallons of drugs... rather than practice in a deep undesrtanding through many lives of meditation to get compassion and wisdom of all of thing and being enlightened.

Answer (score 12):

You are reading too much into it.

The Buddha's enlightenment came from an understanding of the relationships of all things.  The relationships extending to infinity.  This enlightenment imbues the realisation that property and desire are irrelevant.

Lucy's consciousness was dissociated from her body by the drugs, enabling her to not only travel in time and space but also to manipulate them.  She had no desire as she effectively had everything in the universe at her disposal - there was nothing left to desire.

I would also like to think that if the writers were inspired by Buddhism, there would have been less violence in the film.

Comment: "*[...] were inspired by Buddhism, there would have been less violence in the film.*" + 1

Comment: Best to avoid reading too much into *anything* Luc Besson works on. Just go along with the ride.

Answer (score -2):

I Think the movie is not about the Buddhism or any religion its a view of what could theoretically be if could use more "power" of our own brain.

There is an other view of that in the movie [Limitless](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4422836/) without the ability to modifying matter.

Btw.:
There is a really nice answer about the "Time Travelling" [in this Question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/did-lucy-travel-time-or-was-her-mind-imagining-portraying-the-views).

Answer (score -2):

I think the similarity with Buddhism is only the concept of enlightenment, not the whole story in this movie.